# Having trouble using database data in vue app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I've been trying to get multiple profiles from a database and use v-for to try and display them all but whenever I try it doesn't work on and I can't figure out how to get it to use the data which should be getting imported.
Below is what the javascript file looks like.

```
import { projectFirestore } from "../Firebase/Config";
import { ref } from "vue"

const getPremium = () => {
    const Premium = ref([])
    const error = ref(null)

    const load = async () => {
        try{
            const res = await projectFirestore.collection('Premium').get()

            Premium.value = res.docs.map(doc => {
               console.log(doc.data())
               return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
            })
        }
        catch (err){
            error.value = err.message
            console.log(error.value)
        }
    }

    return { Premium, error, load}
}

export default getPremium
```

And heres the vue where I am trying to use v-for to create the profiles.

```
<script>
import getPremium from "../Composables/getPremium.js";
const {Premium, error, load} = getPremium();
load();
</script>
<template>
<div v-for =" Premium in getPremiums" :key="Premium.id" >
 <div class= "hover:scale-105 transition ease-in-out duration-300 bg-neutral-800 hover:bg-neutral-900 active:bg-neutral-900 text-neutral-400 font-bold rounded-xl">
  <br>
     <p>{{ Premium.Name }}</p>
     <img src="../assets/Sample-pic.png" class="object-contain ml-6 w-60 h-80 transition ease-in-out duration-300">
     <div class="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-fit text-left ml-6">
     <p>Location:</p>
     <p>{{ Premium.Location }}</p>
     <p>Rates:</p>
     <p>{{ Premium.Rates }} /hr</p>
     <p>Phone:</p>
     <p>{{ Premium.Phone }}</p>
   
    </div><br>
  </div>
  </div>

</template>
```

I'm not sure what I need to do from here to get it to work properly, I'm new to using databases and any help would be greatly appreciated, Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Besides, you are trying to iterate through function, you iterate it using `in` operator. In operator iterates object properties, no arrays. And created variables call using **first small character** not big one like you have in code "Premium".

```js
<script>
  import getPremium from "../Composables/getPremium.js";
  const { premiumList, error, load } = getPremiumList(); // Name variables, functions with first small letter not big one. Interfaces, Clases with first big letter. Add "List" or "s" in end of name so everyone knows it is array.
  load();
</script>
<template>
    <main>
        <div v-for="item of premiumList" :key="item.id">
            <div
                class="hover:scale-105 transition ease-in-out duration-300 bg-neutral-800 hover:bg-neutral-900 active:bg-neutral-900 text-neutral-400 font-bold rounded-xl"
            >
                <br />
                <p>{{ item.Name }}</p>
                <img
                    src="../assets/Sample-pic.png"
                    class="object-contain ml-6 w-60 h-80 transition ease-in-out duration-300"
                />
                <div class="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-fit text-left ml-6">
                    <p>Location:</p>
                    <p>{{ item.Location }}</p>
                    <p>Rates:</p>
                    <p>{{ item.Rates }} /hr</p>
                    <p>Phone:</p>
                    <p>{{ item.Phone }}</p>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are destructuring Premium from getPremium(), so that is what you should use in your v-for

```
    <script>
import getPremium from "../Composables/getPremium.js";
const { Premium, error, load } = getPremium();
load();
</script>
<template>
    <main>
        <div v-for="item in Premium" :key="item.id">
            <div
                class="hover:scale-105 transition ease-in-out duration-300 bg-neutral-800 hover:bg-neutral-900 active:bg-neutral-900 text-neutral-400 font-bold rounded-xl"
            >
                <br />
                <p>{{ item.Name }}</p>
                <img
                    src="../assets/Sample-pic.png"
                    class="object-contain ml-6 w-60 h-80 transition ease-in-out duration-300"
                />
                <div class="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-fit text-left ml-6">
                    <p>Location:</p>
                    <p>{{ item.Location }}</p>
                    <p>Rates:</p>
                    <p>{{ item.Rates }} /hr</p>
                    <p>Phone:</p>
                    <p>{{ item.Phone }}</p>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks but is there anything else I'm doing wrong because it still doesn't work?

Comment: Can you share what you get when you call console.log(doc.data()) inside getPremium and also if you console.log Premium in the template.

Comment: I get Missing or insufficient permissions. in the console?

Comment: I don't know about firebase but It may be something with your Firestore security rules, probably not allow to read and write for some reason. I am sure if you google firebase Missing or insufficient permissions you will get some good answers stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes it was the rules in the database were set to false not true for read and writes, Thanks.